# How to iterate a readonly array while maintaining array entry typing in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to strictly type a `Map`, so that it can only contain keys that are present in the given readonly array, which I type using the following helper:

```js
type ArrayValues<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer ArrayValues>
  ? ArrayValues
  : never;
```

The Map is getting the correct typings, but when looping over the array, I need to add a manual cast to the `ArrayValues` type I gave the map, this seems like a possibility for errors as this could be casting elements that are not actually inside of the array so it should give me an error instead of going trough.

```js
function test<Buttons extends ReadonlyArray<string | number>>(
  buttonPins: Buttons
) {
  const buttonMap = new Map() as Map<ArrayValues<Buttons>, boolean>;

  buttonPins.forEach((buttonPin) => {
    // This gives error
    //    Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayValues<Buttons>'.
    //      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ArrayValues<Buttons>'.
    // buttonMap.set(buttonPin, true);
    // Using the cast everything works as I want it too
    buttonMap.set(buttonPin as ArrayValues<Buttons>, true);
  });

  return buttonMap;
}
```

The full sample code can be found here:

[image: Edit dawn-forest-1k1z4c]

**Question is:** Is there a better way to iterate over the given array (`buttonPins`) to automatically fix the typing, or is there a better way to make sure we don't inject wrong values into the `buttonMap`?

I've tried some different variations of the generic type of the `test` function, but none of them helped me get further to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type `ArrayValues` can be written simply as the following:

```
type ArrayValues<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = T[number];
```

Since you were using a conditional type with a generic, TypeScript was lazily evaluating it and so it gets fuzzy over whether or not the usage of `buttonMap.set` was valid.

However, the fix is simple. Use `Buttons[number]` instead. TypeScript won't lazily evaluate this so it allows you to set `buttonPin` in the map.

```
function test<Buttons extends ReadonlyArray<string | number>>(
  buttonPins: Buttons
) {
  const buttonMap = new Map<Buttons[number], boolean>();

  buttonPins.forEach((buttonPin) => {
    buttonMap.set(buttonPin, true);
  });

  return buttonMap;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEgKYDsCuI4F84BmUEOARDAM4C0G2VmMwANqQNwCwAUF6gB6Sw4tHAEl0YBgAVg6Coi5w4AIQCqAFTUB5AHIB9AIxwAvHABMAZgA0C5eq17TxuKX0AGUl1xcuAYwiz4ACMGGH9pWSc0LBAACjEJGHCKAEoAOgBzVBgANQBDJkxUChjkjm5OAkx0H0Z-OBgimAAeJRD-OT4G9AATOQAlVFzu-yYATwBBKChc0aaKGCgZdLgAHzhowNQoAD5tmJtgmFD0JIAuZTbZLmT5TkU-ALhD44BZXLAndFQAdzg3sBalwoAG0NlsALqWJ4QCBMQboPalbx3J6XJKpAjQACiuR8AAsYjFnmEZDcjNtbopFMT0P9UhQskS0TIoQtCkiUbgOTYoFlMFB0Kijv5-mUvOUHvMha93k4GvMmcKTjIUmVfO1YahUkwIOlFTKwBlGfEpCrUqoNDoDMkOUA)

---

Another thing, `Map` takes two generic parameters. You don't need to cast to `Map<..., ...>`; you can simply use `new Map<..., ...>()`. This is the same for `Set` and their weak counterparts.

Comment: I was aware of the Map typing options, this was probably not clear in the example but the casting stems from a more complex construction in another part of the code :).
It's the `Buttons[number]` part that I was missing and indeed solves all my issues! Awesome that the solution is so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this (see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAaogNgVwgZwDwAqUEAHsBAHYAmOUAShIlQPYXojxIh6YUDWFZgHcKAPlFQAvFCKly1Wgyat2nZHgCWFAGYQ4sBMjRZcogFBQoAfgNdj2HBagAuKBQgA3PQG4zZ7bwAxsAarFDkOMB4AEKYwMCstHKUNPSMLGwchtyRcFoA5lAAPm6YALYARnqiADQyxGQptGqoGA4xcQkUOOIAFE4VnawAClo4rnDpKiAyANoAumYAlK4AsohghHUVzMzojGJQAN5OgYnAUIPxrOtgUm4QQlC3W5e7%204hivUu%20A0MUo26ADptMw4ABRRCBAAWvV6Vy6gKWUgkJ0slgRNw2QJwEGA8P%20gLqwDg2B%20TgAvuSnJNgJg4BRLv9br4KX4zt0LhFgC17rMAOSIfl1ACMdQADKK6vzufz5lBELQOZFfAB6VXPDZ4QX84pQEV68V6mW4YDCt57A7mZVc023e7c3rclo-IA))

```
type ArrayValues<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer ArrayValues>
  ? ArrayValues
  : never;

function test<Buttons extends ReadonlyArray<string | number>, T extends ArrayValues<Buttons>>(
  buttonPins: readonly T[]
): Map<T, boolean> {
  const buttonMap = new Map<T, boolean>();

  buttonPins.forEach((buttonPin) => {
    buttonMap.set(buttonPin, true);
  });

  return buttonMap;
}

const testArray = ['a', 1, 0, 1, 'test'] as const;
// Map<'a' | 1 | 0 | 'test', boolean>
const testMap = test(testArray);
```